# Products not adding to cart (Exp:resso Store 2.0.6)

Tags: expresso-store, shopping-cart

Running on my localhost, I can't get Store 2 to add products to the cart.

- I've completely removed my .htaccess file and set my index page to `index.php` to eliminate rewrites as a potential cause.
- You do not need to be logged-in to purchase (via settings)
- SSL is not required for checkout actions (via settings)
- Running EE 2.7.2 and Store 2.0.6

My template code looks like:

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="cart/index" disable_javascript="yes"}
    <button class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
{/exp:store:product}
```

Which renders to:

```
<form method="post" class="store_product_form">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline;">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="cart/index">
    <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="2786">
    <input type="hidden" name="nosubmit" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="41">
    <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="book/[url_title_redacted]">
    <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_params" value="69KWfitkNRkGcCM70xb/xVBDRDgS8b+Gidj4Jm17QqWWwRtxKugeyL9rqZbeUJCEoAjGCVwAIpUaWG9crrWenIab/MHr9uS1p/7XVJNV9Ei5jfM0Crio4DhMjdb0GvizwuV4r5x2Qx3GlbWHpNJ9+RPXrGkZEamm/FaJJIaTBzM=">
    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="785db0072762b9f7c3397ea0e4b95f9a5efbf092">
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

After submission, I get to my **/cart** template, but only the contents of my `{if no_items}` conditional displays. Removing the `{if no_items}` conditional results in no output between the `store:checkout` tag pair at all.

Where to troubleshoot next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a item_qty field to tell Store how many products to add to the cart.

```
<input name="item_qty" value="1">
```

---

Also, there is a debug tag that will help you see what's happening in your cart more clearly. Pop this into any of your templates:

```
{exp:store:checkout_debug}
```

Comment: For the win! Gracias Anna.

Comment: If you only want the user to add a single of any product quantity you can also use `<input type="hidden" name="item_qty" value="1" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help, but I have a the same setup to yours and I have found that product URLs that have a period do not add to cart while without do.

So for example "item_no.2" will not add, while "item_no2" will.

I'm currently trying to work out if it's related to buildwithstructure potentially.